# pandas DataFrames aggregate min max mean

Tags: pandas

Есть DataFrame `columns=['author_id', 'author_name', 'book_title', 'price']`

Нужно получить DataFrame `columns=['author_name', 'max_price', 'min_price']`

Желательно через

```
groupby('author_name').agg({'price': 'min', 'price': 'max'})
```

И тут сложности, так как агрегация по одному и тому же полю, + не могу сразу задать имена новых поле. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A','tite1',1],[1, 'A','title2',2],[1, 'A','title3',3]],
     columns=['author_id', 'author_name', 'book_title', 'price'])
```

Или так

```
df.groupby('author_name').agg(mix_price=('price', 'min'), max_price=('price', 'max'))
```

или так

```
df.groupby('author_name')['price'].agg(mix_price='min', max_price='max')
```

результат будет один и тот же

```
            mix_price  max_price
author_name                      
A                    1         3
```

---

можно и так, обычным синтаксисом с тем же результатом

```
df.groupby('author_name')['price'].agg(['min', 'max']) \
  .rename(columns={'min':'price_min', 'max':'price_max'})
```

Comment: Спасибо. По поводу именованных параметров в agg не подумал и не увидел ни одного примера.

Comment: я на stackoverflow подсмотрел :) уже не помню где

Comment: @KamoPetrosyan я написал, как это можно было бы "традиционно" сделать :)